# What is the ASP.NET Core equivalent to HttpRequestMessage?

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I found a [blog post](http://bizcoder.com/posting-raw-json-to-web-api) that shows how POSTed JSON can be received as a string.

I want to know what's the new native way to do the same thing as the following code in a REST Post method in a Controller:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var jsonString = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    // Do something with the string 

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
}
```

The other option bellow does not work for me, i think because I don't use `Content-Type: application/json` in the request header (can't change this), and I get a 415 .

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]JToken jsonbody)
{
    // Process the jsonbody 

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In .Net Core they have merged the Web API and MVC so you could just do it like this with [`IActionResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iactionresult) or one of its derivatives.

```
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]JToken jsonbody)
{
    // Process the jsonbody 

    return Created("", null);// pass the url and the object if you want to return them back or you could just leave the url empty and pass a null object
}
```